# InputStream with files larger than 2 gb

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I am trying to send files to a server. I get an Uri, get a `inputstream` with `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)`, and then proceed to read chunks of the file and send them to the server via multi part.

This all works fine, until the file I try to send is larger than 2gb. When the file exceeds that value, the process works fine until ~2gb, then the result of calling .read() is -1, even if the file is nowhere near completely read.

After searching the web, I found that `inputstream` reads are limited to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. But I have found no work-around for this. So i guess my question is, is there some method with which I can read past 2gb?

Here is the mentioned code:

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(fileUri);

if (is != null) {

    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = AppController.UPLOAD_CHUNK_SIZE;
    buffer = new byte[maxBufferSize];

    int fileChunk = 0;
    int read;

    while ((read = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {

        boolean didSend = sendMultipartChunk(upFile, fileChunk, buffer);
        if (didSend) {
            fileChunk++;
        } else {
            uploadedFiles.add(new UploadableFileDTO(true));
            checkIfFinished();
            break;
            }


    }
    is.close();
    sendEndUpload(upFile);
```

Comment: `read()` is limited to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, but then so is the size of the byte array you are reading into, so why this is a problem remains obscure. Exceeding this does not cause `read()` to return -1. The only thing that does that is reaching end of file. You're barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: `boolean didSend = sendMultipartChunk(upFile, fileChunk, buffer);` ??? How could that work? You should take into account how many bytes are in that buffer. How many are `read` like `boolean didSend = sendMultipartChunk(upFile, fileChunk, buffer, read);`

Comment: I have tested this with multiple file extensions and multiple file sizes. Each time the file is under 2gb everything works fine, whenever it is over 2gb , it reads up to that point then returns -1 (even with a 10gb file). The only thing i have found that is even remotely related to this issue is the fact that inputstream.read() is limited to 2gb.

Comment: Rubbish. It is limited to the size of the buffer. The size of the buffer is `AppController.UPLOAD_CHUNK_SIZE`. This is less than 2GB, by definition. This is not the problem. You're barking up the wrong tree. You are also ignoring the byte count returned by `read()` when writing, as already pointed out by @greenapps. Fix your code.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the OP needs to specify a data structure he wants to read into that can sustain more than 2GB in main memory first.